# Search functionality of select / option tags using div & a tags - i.e. upon typing the first letter/s using keyboard it jumps to the link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need to add in a keyboard quick select functionality to a dropdown, like you get with select & option tags i.e. when in the dropdown, typing the first couple of letters jumps to the corresponding entry.

I'm struggling to get the same functionality using the select & options tags, so would prefer using the current set up if possible?

Personally I think the search function at the top is a better option - but the directors are rather stuck in their ways and want both the search function and the old jump to option using keyboard.

HTML:

```
<div class="click">View full list of properties</div>
  <div class="dropDown">
    <div id="myDropDown" class="dropDownContent">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." spellcheck="false"; id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
      <a href="#support">Support</a>
      <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#base">Base</a>
      <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
      <a href="#support">Support</a>
      <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.click { cursor: pointer; }

/* The search field */
#myInput {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 15px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00a8a8;
}

/* The search field when it gets focus/clicked on */
#myInput:focus { border: 2px solid #00a8a8; border-radius: 3px; outline: none; margin: 0; }

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropDown {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropDownContent {
  display: none;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropDownContent a {
  color: #666;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropDownContent a:hover { background-color: rgba(0, 168, 168, 0.3); }


@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  .dropDownContent {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .dropDownContent a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .dropDownContent {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
         $(".dropDownContent").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $(".dropDownContent").on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".dropDownContent").hide();
});

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SimonW9/Lkm5ybtd/77/

Any ideas if this is possible?

Many thanks!
Simon

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. Documentation in the code.

```js
var myString;
/* 
  Display or hide options when select box is clicked on 
*/
$("body").on("click", ".selected", function() {
  /*
    Reset
  */
  myString = "";
  $(".option").css("background-color", "white");
  
  $(this).next(".options").toggleClass("open");
  /*
    Attach or detach keypress function to document
  */
  if ( $("ul.options").hasClass("open")) {
    $(document).on( "keypress", checkKey )
  } else {
    $(document).off( "keypress", checkKey )
  }
});
/* 
  Display chosen option and display in select box 
*/
$("body").on("click", ".option", function() {
  $(".selected").html($(this).html());
  $(".options").toggleClass("open");
});

checkKey = function(e) {
  /*
    Build the string that needs to be searched for
  */ 
  myString = myString + e.key.toLowerCase();
  /*
    Evaluate the options
  */
  $(".option").each(function() {
    /*
      Check if the lowercase acharacter is present in the option
    */
    let position = $(this).text().toLowerCase().search(myString);
    /*
      Display the option when the character has position = 1
    */
    if ( position == 0) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
      $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

.selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="selected">Select an option</div>
  <ul class="options">
    <li class="option">Support</li>
    <li class="option">Surround</li>
    <li class="option">Tools</li>
    <li class="option">About</li>
    <li class="option">Around</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time!  It's a solution, but doesn't fulfil the requirements sadly - as the link needs to open a pop-up window, with all the links, as well as including the search functionality.  If not, I could just use select / option tags....! Basically needs to act like a dropdown once opened.